# scrolling graphicsWidget using mouse

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

im adding QGraphicsLayoutItem in a QGraphicsWidget in run time using QGraphicsLinearLayout.

i have to add more items to the layout  that exceeds the height of the viewport height and items shown outside the viewport area.so is it possible to pan or scroll in QGraphicsWidget like QGraphicsView. QGraphicsView i can pan using  centerOn and showing only a visible rect.

the normal view [image]

and when more item added

[image]

Comment: i had added some screenshots

Comment: Why not using a QGraphicsView instead?

Comment: you mean to say i have to add a qgraphicsView inside the qgraphicsview as proxyItem ..? is it not possible to do on the item itself ..?